# Infinity loop issue using for loops

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import yfinance as yf
import money_18
import talib


def backtest(df,us_code, profit_target, stop_loss, macd_diff):

    pos_opened = False
    open_price  = 0
    close_price = 0
    pnl = 0
    pnl_list = []

    original_capital = 100000
    temp_capital = original_capital
    num_of_lot = 0
    equity_value = 0
    equity_value_list = []

    dd_dollar = 0
    dd_dollar_list = []
    dd_pct = 0
    dd_pct_list = []
    mdd_dollar = 0
    mdd_pct    = 0

    total_profit = 0
    num_of_trade = 0

    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        now_date          = df.loc[i,'Date']
        now_open          = df.loc[i,'Open']
        now_high          = df.loc[i,'High']
        now_low           = df.loc[i,'Low']
        now_close         = df.loc[i,'Close']
        now_rsi           = df.loc[i,'RSI']
        now_upper_band    = df.loc[i,'Upper_Band']
        now_middle_band   = df.loc[i,'Middle_Band']
        now_lower_band    = df.loc[i,'Lower_Band']
        now_macd          = df.loc[i,'MACD']
        now_macd_signal   = df.loc[i,'MACD_Signal']
        now_macd_hist     = df.loc[i,'MACD_Hist']



        ##### equity curve #####
        equity_value = round(temp_capital + (now_open - open_price) * num_of_lot )
        equity_value_list.append(equity_value)

        temp_max_equity = max(equity_value_list)
        dd_dollar = temp_max_equity - equity_value
        dd_dollar_list.append(dd_dollar)
        mdd_dollar = max(dd_dollar_list)

        dd_pct = (temp_max_equity - equity_value) / temp_max_equity
        dd_pct_list.append(dd_pct)
        mdd_pct = max(dd_pct_list)

        ##### open position #####
        if (pos_opened == False) and (i < len(df) - 1) and now_macd_hist > macd_diff :
            pos_opened = True
            open_price = now_close
            num_of_lot = temp_capital // (open_price)


        ##### profit taking and stop loss #####
        if (pos_opened == True) and ((now_open - open_price > profit_target * open_price) or (now_open - open_price < stop_loss * open_price) or (i == len(df) -1)):
            pos_opened  = False
            close_price = now_open
            pnl = (close_price - open_price) * num_of_lot
            pnl_list.append(pnl)

            open_price = 0
            num_of_lot = 0
            temp_capital = temp_capital + pnl


    if len(pnl_list) > 0:
        total_profit = sum(pnl_list)
        num_of_trade = len(pnl_list)

    return us_code, profit_target, stop_loss, total_profit, num_of_trade, mdd_dollar, mdd_pct, macd_diff

if __name__ == '__main__':

    us_code_list = ['TSLA', 'AAPL']
    macd_diff_list = [0, 0.05]
    profit_target_list = [0.03, 0.06]
    stop_loss_list = [-0.01, -0.02, -0.03]

    start_date = '2020-01-01'
    end_date = '2020-12-31'

    df_dict = {}

    for us_code in us_code_list:
        df= yf.Ticker(us_code).history(start=start_date, end=end_date)
        df= df[df['Volume'] > 0]
        df = df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]
        df['RSI'] = talib.RSI(df['Close'], timeperiod=14)
        df['Upper_Band'], df['Middle_Band'], df['Lower_Band'] = talib.BBANDS(df['Close'], 20, 2, 2)
        df['MACD'], df['MACD_Signal'], df['MACD_Hist'] = talib.MACD(df['Close'], fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26,
                                                                             signalperiod=9)
        df = df[df['MACD_Hist'].notna()]
        df = df.reset_index()
        df_dict[us_code] = df

    save_us_code       = ''
    save_macd_diff     = 0
    save_profit_target = 0
    save_stop_loss     = 0
    total_profit       = 0
    num_of_trade       = 0
    mdd_dollar         = 0
    mdd_pct            = 0

    save_us_code_list       = []
    save_macd_diff_list     = []
    save_profit_target_list = []
    save_stop_loss_list     = []
    total_profit_list       = []
    num_of_trade_list       = []
    mdd_dollar_list         = []
    mdd_pct_list            = []

    result_dict = {}

    for us_code in us_code_list:
        for macd_diff in macd_diff_list:
            for profit_target in profit_target_list:
                for stop_loss in stop_loss_list:

                    print(us_code, macd_diff, profit_target, stop_loss) ## the problem should be starting from here##

                    save_us_code, save_profit_target, save_stop_loss, total_profit, num_of_trade, mdd_dollar, mdd_pct, macd_diff = backtest(df, us_code, profit_target, stop_loss, macd_diff)
                    save_us_code_list.append(save_us_code)
                    save_profit_target_list.append(save_profit_target)
                    save_stop_loss_list.append(save_stop_loss)
                    total_profit_list.append(total_profit)
                    num_of_trade_list.append(num_of_trade)
                    mdd_dollar_list.append(mdd_dollar)
                    mdd_pct_list.append(mdd_pct)
                    macd_diff_list.append(macd_diff)
```

1. I am working on the algo trade, however, I created a for loop to put my parameter into my backtest function.  However, the for loop keeps looping non-stop.
2. I think the error starting from "for macd_diff in macd_diff_list:" because i try to print the result below that row, the result is already indefinite.

Comment: Without a [mre] or any examples of the output of this, there's not much we can do to help. My guess is that maybe your lists are just really long. What's the size of each one?

Comment: there is only 168 rows for the coding but dunno how to put up to here

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow.....fourth week for learning programming XD...

Comment: All your lists are finite. As @RandomDavis said, it is very likely your lists are just very long.

Maybe you can try by printing the list one by one first ?

Comment: You need to edit your post to include an actual question and/or expectation in order for the community to be able to answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've shown the full code, your problem is obvious. Your original example didn't show the issue because you didn't include all relevant code. Here's your example with the relevant code that's causing the issue:

```
for us_code in us_code_list:
        for macd_diff in macd_diff_list:
            for profit_target in profit_target_list:
                for stop_loss in stop_loss_list:
                    ... # irrelevant code not shown
                    macd_diff_list.append(macd_diff)
```

The issue is that you're looping through each item in `macd_diff_list`, but then for each loop iteration, you *add an item* to that list. So of course the loop will be infinite. You need to be looping through a different list, or adding items to a different list.